# How to reset every input data which we've rendered on every input in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios, { Axios } from "axios";
import {
  ContainerDiv,
  InnerDiv,
  StyledButton,
  StyledInput,
} from "./StyledComponents";
function WeatherCard() {
  const [input, SetInput] = useState("");
  const [apiData, setApiData] = useState([]);
  const [temp, setTemp] = useState([]);
  const [minTemp, setMinTemp] = useState([]);
  const [maxTemp, setMaxTemp] = useState([]);
  const [pressure, setPressure] = useState([]);
  const [humidity, setHumidity] = useState([]);
  const [error, setError] = useState([]);
  const [wind, setWind] = useState([]);

  const handleOnChange = (e) => {
    SetInput(e.target.value);
    console.log(input);
  };

  const handleButtonClick = () => {
    axios
      .get(
        `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${input}&appid=0f5ee70dcdfa521f9fbd0cacb97d71b7`
      )

      .then((data) => {
        setApiData(data.data.weather);
        setTemp(Math.round(data.data.main.temp - 273));
        setMinTemp(Math.round(data.data.main.temp_min - 273));
        setMaxTemp(Math.round(data.data.main.temp_max - 273));
        setPressure(data.data.main.pressure);
        setHumidity(data.data.main.humidity);
        setWind(data.data.wind.speed);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        setError(`${input} City not found.`);
      });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <ContainerDiv>
        <InnerDiv>
          <label for="city">City: </label>
          <StyledInput
            type="text"
            value={input}
            onChange={handleOnChange}
            name="city"
          ></StyledInput>
          <StyledButton onClick={handleButtonClick}>
            Get Weather Data
          </StyledButton>
        </InnerDiv>
      </ContainerDiv>
      <ContainerDiv>
        <div>
          {apiData.map((item) => {
            return <p>Weather: {item.description}</p>;
          })}

          <p>Temperature: {temp}°C</p>
          <p>Minimum Temperature: {minTemp}°C</p>
          <p>Maximum Temperature: {maxTemp}°C</p>
          <p>Pressure: {pressure}pa</p>
          <p>Humidity:{humidity}%</p>
          <p>Wind Speed: {wind}</p>
          <p>Error: {error}</p>
        </div>
      </ContainerDiv>
    </>
  );
}

export default WeatherCard;
```

"in this code the last results are there if we get any error i.e. by typing wrong city name, the problem is that the last data is still there and there is error which we cant tell if its for new input or last input.   please dont mind my english as it is my third language"

i want to reset rendered data on every input.

Comment: You want an empty input when you click on the button.

Answer (score 1):

just set your states to an empty string after getting an error

```js
      .catch((e) => {
        setError(`${input} City not found.`);
        setApiData([]);
        setTemp('');
        setMinTemp('');
        setMaxTemp('');
        setPressure('');
        setHumidity('');
        setWind('');
      }
```

Comment: anytime .... : )